# Setup Airbrake-js with a ReactJS app and webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, airbrake

I'm trying to integrate [Airbrake-js](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js) into my dev setup to report on JavaScript errors. My app is a React app that uses webpack.

I've been scouring the web for a couple of hours now to figure out how the setup should be. I haven't been able to pinpoint in their [documentation](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js#basic-usage) where their starting code:

```
var airbrakeJs = require('airbrake-js');
var airbrake = new airbrakeJs({projectId: 1, projectKey: 'abc'});
```

should actually be positioned. My thinking is that I want my existing app wrapped in their wrap function (showing only part of my app.js file for brevity):

```
var airbrakeJs = require('airbrake-js'),
    React  = require('react'),
    ReactDOM = require('react-dom'),
    Relay = require('react-relay'),
    App = require('./components/app'),
    Router = require ('react-router'),
    Route = require Router.Route, 
    createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');

var startApp = function() {
  // This will throw if the document has no head tag.
  // ****What does this exactly do?**** 
  document.head.insertBefore(document.createElement("style"));
}
startApp = airbrake.wrap(myApp);

// Any exceptions thrown in startApp will be reported to Airbrake.
startApp();

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={createBrowserHistory()} createElement={ReactRouterRelay.createElement}>
    <Route component={App} queries={AppQueries} {...renderProps}>
      <Route path="/somewhere" component={Somewhere} queries={SomewhereQueries} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('academy-body'));
```

So, I added this to my entry point app.js file (where I also handle my Router logic) but it is not being called there, so I must be doing something wrong. I also don't exactly know what the second line (right below the first comment) exactly does.

Can anyone explain and help get Airbrake properly setup? Is Airbrake-js even going to work with a React app?

Any help in the right direction is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate airbrake with

```
window.airbrake = new airbrakeJs({projectId: 1, projectKey: 'abc'});
// replace projectId and projectKey with your project values
```

so first you may try just adding that to your existing code. Note that we are using `window` global scope to access Airbrake's instance from any child scope. Usually this is not a good practice but looks fair enough for Airbreake's purposes.

This line

```
 document.head.insertBefore(document.createElement("style"));
```

it is just an example, used at the documentation, of something that may throw an error. You can remove it from yout code.

This is to wrap Airbrake around specific functions.

```
startApp = airbrake.wrap(myApp);

// Any exceptions thrown in startApp will be reported to Airbrake.
startApp();
```

You can remove it from your code.

You can use this to debug if Airbrake is actually catching errors:

```
// Remove it for production or use an enviroment conditional

airbrake.addReporter(function(notice) {
  console.log(notice);
});
```